# Racket localhost doesn't find files from <a href>

Tags: servlets, webserver, racket

I'm trying to learn web programming in `Racket`. The question is this: when I'm clicking `<a>` link my localhost writes that "file in not found", although the link is all right. When in turn I run file that link points to in Dr. Racket  localhost is ok. Why is that? Also how do I redirect in `Racket`?

Comment: I feel it has something to do with #:servlet-path or some other parameter. Just can't figure it out

Comment: Do you have some small example code you could share that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: @AsumuTakikawa, @benrudgers I've tried `(define (start req) \`(html (head (title"")) (body (a ((href = "/hello.rkt"))"go"))) (serve-servlet start #:servlet-path "/query.rkt")`, where file "hello.rkt"  and "query.rkt" are in the same directory

Comment: JFYI, in the future it would be helpful if you provided example code that will actually run. Your example there has some syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide extra paths for files that the web server should serve via the `#:extra-files-paths` option for [serve/servlet](http://docs.racket-lang.org/web-server/run.html?q=serve%2Fservlet#%28def._%28%28lib._web-server%2Fservlet-env..rkt%29._serve%2Fservlet%29%29).

Here's an example based on what you provided in comments:

```
#lang web-server

(require web-server/servlet-env)

(define (start req)
  (response/xexpr
   `(html (head (title"")) (body (a ((href "/hello.rkt"))"go")))))

;; assuming the module is in /tmp and run from there
(serve/servlet start #:servlet-path "/query.rkt"
               ;; whatever extra file paths you need
               ;; in this example hello.rkt is in /tmp
               #:extra-files-paths (list "/tmp"))
```